# How do I apply changes on this editor?

Tags: windows, git, vim, vi, git-cherry-pick

While using GIT on the console and cherry picking this editor appeared. And I don't know how to apply/send the changes and move on

[image: Git screen]

Comment: Look up the "vi" or "vim" editor. It's admittedly nasty if you encounter it for the first time, but in no time you'll get to love it and start looking down on people using Emacs ;)

Comment: To just close, enter `:q`.

Comment: ZZ will do the trick

Comment: you might want to look through https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[git]+[windows]+editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save changes and quit, type `:wq`

Vim and Vi have different modes you can edit in.  This allows users to use the main part of the keyboard for shortcuts ;)

If you are struggling to make changes in the first place, you have to enter insert mode by pressing `i`, then make your changes.  You then have to go back to command mode by pressing `Esc`, then you can save and quit with `:wq`.

I agree with the other answers that you should use a different editor, unless you want to commit to learning Vim.  Vim is great for learning to edit code super efficiently, but it's quite tricky to get your head around at first.

Answer (score 0):

nano is another user friendly editor . 
Unfortunately, nano does not come with the Windows version of Git.

You need to install nano.

Before making your first commit, try running:

```
nano
```

in the terminal. The result should be a simple editor with instructions at the bottom of the screen; close/quit with ctrl-X. If that worked.

```
git config --global core.editor nano
```

will configure Git to use the nano editor. The commands to use the text editor (like copy, paste, quit, etc.) will be shown on the bottom of the screen

Answer (score -1):

This is a editor which git will launch according your default editor configuration.
Commonly, it is determined by your EDITOR environment variables, or configured by the the following command

> sudo update-alternatives --config editor

You can do what I mentioned above to check what this editor is, and set your favorite editor to substitute it. After you change your default editor configuration, you can avoid this editor be launched again.

Comment: he has windows, it's visible from the screenshot

Comment: @max630 I know he has windows, but I also notice the*MinGW64* on title bar, which means he is using a unix-like shell environment on windows.

Comment: But it definitely does not have sudo and most probably no update-alternatives as well